# reject to add arguments in the color type

Tags: java, android, animation, colors, paint

I am working on painting line, I faced a basic problem with changing the color :S:S

I have the following code, I got an error in the last line of code I cant add argument to new Color(???) >> I cant add the R, G, B color numbers

```
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Random random = new Random();
        int R = (int)(Math.random()*256);
        int G = (int)(Math.random()*256);
        int B= (int)(Math.random()*256);
        paint.setColor(new Color(R , G , B));
```

Comment: Is not the maximum value to be given to R,G,B 255??

Comment: @HareshChaudhary `Math.random()` produces a `float` less than `1.0`, therefore multiplying it by 256 will always be <256, or in `int`, <=255.

Comment: @Eric thanks for clearing the Doubt...cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a `Color` object like that. `Color` is just a static Android helper class that handles color-based operations.

Try this:

```
paint.setColor(Color.rgb(R , G , B));
```

For reference, see the [`Color.rgb(...)` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#rgb%28int,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: I will do, but the system refused to accept in less than 10 min